# Randomly choosing elements from array without choosing an element twice

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 arrays that are shuffled in the same way. Basically I want to remove the array elements once it's been asked to avoid getting duplicates being printed out:

How do I go about this, do I need to use an array list? I am completely lost.

```
/*
 * *** Random Test ***
 * Allows the user to generate a random test
 * from a bank of 10 questions.
 */

// import java libraries
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class randomTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);


    // Question bank
    String[] qBank = new String[] {"What is the capital of England?", 
            "Which animal comes first in the English dictionary",
            "How many days are there in a leap year?"};

    // Answer bank
    String[] aBank = new String[] {"London", 
            "Aardvark", 
            "366"};

    // How many questions?
    System.out.println("How many questions would you like? (1-10)");
    int numQuestions = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    int asked = 0;

    // Already Asked
    int[] alreadyAsked = new int[numQuestions];


    while (numQuestions != asked) {

        // Random question
        int idx = new Random().nextInt(qBank.length);
        String question = (qBank[idx]);
        System.out.println(question);


        System.out.println("Enter your awnswer: ");
        String myAnswer = sc.nextLine();
        asked ++;


        if (myAnswer.equals(aBank[idx])) {
            System.out.println("Correct answer!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong answer");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an `ArrayList<String>` will be your best solution, then you can just do `list.remove()` to remove entries as they are used.

Collections.shuffle() will shuffle one list. What you probably actually want to do though is just choose one element at random from the list each time around the loop:

```
 List<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
 questions.add("question 1");
 questions.add("question 2");
 etc
 List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
 answers.add("answer 1");
 etc

 Random random = new Random();

 while (questionsRemaining-- > 0) {
     int q = random.nextInt(questions.size());
     // ask question questions.get(q);
     // check against answer answers.get(q);

     // Removed used
     questions.remove(q);
     answers.remove(q);
 }
```

Really though you would be better off defining a Question object and having both Q and A inside that, then you don't have to maintain two lists and in the future you can add more data (like different scores for different questions, multiple answers, etc).

Comment: Can you suggest to me how I can randomise two different arrays in the same order as it doesn't seem to work when using ArrayList. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a ton man, nooby question but what does a go to? how do I set the a up?

Comment: I have something just like that but I'm getting <b>a cannot be resolved to a variable</b>

Comment: You will need to work it out then, just look at what the error report is, what lines it is on, and what it might mean.

Comment: I jsut don't know where the variable a is defined?

Comment: Tim please help where is a defined?

Comment: @JonathanSaich it was a typo in the answer. should have been q

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want duplicates use a Set. To remove duplicates from a List you can use Set s = new HashSet(list);

Comment: I don't think set is useful here. Because, the problem is not about having duplicate elements, but about not asking same question twice even when they are chosen randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2D array and set the questions and answers together.

```
String[][] example = new String[2][10];
example[0, 0] = "What is the capital of England?";
example[1, 0] = "London";
```

You don't have to type it out the tedious way, it works with the array instantiation you have above (using { }).

Alternatively, an `ArrayList<String[]>`. Just set the `String[]` as `{"question", "answer"}` and add it to the `ArrayList`.